# want to delete a name in database n it must display if the name exists or not

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $username = "ODBC";

    $password = "";

    $dbname = "db_students";

    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

        echo"Connected to database"."<br/>";

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM enrolments
                WHERE student_name = :name");

        $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name,PDO::PARAM_STR,255);

        $name = "Pietie Kock";
        $stmt->execute();

        if($student_name > 0)
        {
           echo "record deleted ". $student_name;
        }else{

           echo "record doesn't exist". $student_name;

            $dbh = null;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You should add a least a question, and some of your problem description.

Comment: its format now and i will do that next time i upload a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$student_name`  is undefined in your code To check the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement we use **[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
        echo "record deleted " . $student_name;
    } else {

        echo "record doesn't exist" . $student_name;

        $dbh = null;
    }
```

You also forget to close `try` Your code would be

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    echo"Connected to database" . "<br/>";

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM enrolments
                WHERE student_name = :name");

    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);

    $name = "Pietie Kock";
    $stmt->execute();


    if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
        echo "record deleted " . $student_name;
    } else {

        echo "record doesn't exist" . $student_name;

        $dbh = null;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {// close you try
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```